# How to get multiple Wishlist name (enterprise feature) by a customer_id

Tags: wishlist, magento-2-commerce, multiplewishlist

I'm trying to get the multiple wishlist by customer_id, but not work

```
protected $wishlistCollectionFactory;
```

--constructor

```
    \Magento\Wishlist\Model\ResourceModel\Wishlist\CollectionFactory $wishlistCollectionFactory
```

.......

```
$this->wishlistCollectionFactory = $wishlistCollectionFactory;
```

actual code in controller

```
if ($action == "wishlist") {

            $customer_id = $this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();
            //var_dump($customer_id);
            $wishlistCollection = $this->wishlistCollectionFactory->create()->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customerId);;
            var_dump(json_encode($wishlistCollection));
            $result->setData(['error' => 0,
                    'message' => __('Operation Success'),
                    'wishlistCollection' => json_encode($wishlistCollection)
                ]
            );
            return $result;
        }
```

the output of wishlist is null, anyone know how to get the wishlist collection in commerce edition?

i want to get the all wishlist names.

Answer (score 0):

changed to use

```
    \Magento\Wishlist\Model\Wishlist $wishlistModel
```

....

```
        $wishlist = $this->wishlistModel->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customer_id);
        //var_dump($wishlist);
        foreach ($wishlist as $list) {
            echo $list->getId().'__'.$list->getName()."<br>";
        }
```